# What is the name of the ubuntu command line software that alters your SSH window to show basic "top command" information?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ssh

I was using an ubuntu server I found via Alestic a few months ago and it had this great little informative box at the bottom of the SSH screen which told me things like:

- current bandwidth upload/download
- current cpu usage
- current memory usage
- etc.

For the life of me, I can't remember what it is called?

I liked it because it was always running and giving me instant feedback about any scripts I was testing.

Comment: This belongs on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: No need for apologies. I guess a lot of people don't know it's there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [byobu](http://byobu.co)?

Comment: That's the one, thanks Martey!